# Can I use regular headphones on transatlantic British Airways 747 flights?

Tags: air-travel, british-airways, in-flight-services

I will soon be traveling, Economy class, transatlantic on a British Airways 747. I was hoping to use my over-the-ear headphones with their armrest entertainment system rather than the earbuds they provide.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

My concern is that their armrests have nonstandard sockets that regular headphone plugs will not work with.

Comment: Not sure about BA but I was able to use it on a Virgin America flight.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

British Airways uses a standard 3.5mm port in all classes; you should be fine to bring your own headphones. **[edit]** However, I always include in my travel electronics kit an airline headphone adapter, which allows you to use your headphones' single 3.5mm stereo jack with the double 3.5mm mono ports found on some equipment, including older BA aircraft.

[image: 2-prong mono to stereo airline headphone adapter]

In premium cabins, you may notice a smaller second outlet, and that the provided headphones have two-prong jacks. This second port is *not* an audio output, but a power supply for the noise cancellation system in the provided headphones. You do not need a one-prong to two-prong adapter here, and you should not attempt to plug any third party accessories into this outlet.

In fact, I'm not aware of any major carrier which has proprietary audio jacks in this day and age. You'll find 3.5mm outlets in single stereo or split mono varieties pretty much anywhere you can get electronic in-flight audio.

Comment: Jet Airways used the 2-pin connector when I traveled with them on long-haul flights between Europe and India six months ago.

Answer (score 7):

If memory serves, many the BA 747s, and some of their other planes use the two pin "Aircaft Headphone" standard in economy and premium economy. (Not sure what the official name is for that). The left and right channels are carried by different 3.5mm mono connectors. You can buy an adapter for a trivial amount of money, which'll convert from twin 3.5mm mono into regular 3.5mm stereo, so you can use your normal headphones. I always carry one with me, as you often need it! I'm pretty sure some of their planes have regular 3.5mm stereo in economy / premium economy.

In Business on BA 747s, there are two sockets, but they're different. One is a normal 3.5mm stereo connection, the other is slightly narrower (2.5mm?) and seems to be used to feed the noise cancelling headphones they lend you. I've not had any problems with plugging my own headphones in. Not sure about first, I've never been lucky enough to fly at the pointy end...

Comment: I thought the 2-prong mono was done away in the 2010 seat replacement program? Or is that only for WT on the 777s?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I had to use my adapter on my last 747 flight, but I have a feeling I didn't need it last autumn on a 777. I find it's generally safest to carry an adapter whenever I fly, then you're covered even if there's an unexpected equipment change!

Answer (score 5):

(March 2024)

[image: BA Headphone Jack in Premium Economy]

I've just flown Premium Economy with British Airways and my standard 3.5mm connector which has worked on every flight I've taken in the past, didn't fit their socket on either of the flights, they seem to have a slightly different fitting. It seemed to be a 3.5mm on one pin and 2.5mm on the other, and the gap between them was slightly smaller than the standard. One is also just slightly longer.

They do provide noise cancelling headphones which are fully sanitised before the flight (they are individually wrapped).

The planes I flew in were a 3 year old 787-10 (Dreamliner) and a 27 year old 777-200 ER, so I assume this is standard on their entire long haul fleet. This was on the London > Chicago route.

Answer (score 3):

While flying in early April 2013, in my economy class seat I found a standard 3.5mm jack. It was a little loose (not surprising), but it worked with my personal over-the-ear headphones. Of the eight video monitors my family sat in front of traveling to London and back, one could not play movies (extremely choppy video) but its map and audio were fine, and another did not retract all the way so small people could not see its screen because the viewing angle was too oblique. The staff was super helpful, however, restarting the monitor with the choppy video when notified (alas, in vain).

Comment: If your IFE was broken, contact customer services and they [should give you some avios in compensation](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1183201-waiting-time-broken-ife-miles.html) - broken IFE forms filled out onboard don't always work, but contacting customer services should, as [this FT thread](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1183201-waiting-time-broken-ife-miles.html) covers

Answer (score 1):

If you push the jack about 1/2 way in to the socket, there is a spot where you get sound in both ears of the headphone.

It may take a bit of fiddling to get it right.

I've travelled on a ton of long haul flights, with many different airlines and brands of earphones, and this trick has never failed for me.

Comment: This method is not as good as a proper adapter, as it pipes one channel into both ears. However, it's certainly beats listening to a movie with sound in one ear only!