# Using airline headphones with own equipment (during a flight)

Tags: air-travel, british-airways, in-flight-services

I have the inverse problem of [Can I use regular headphones on transatlantic British Airways 747 flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14750/can-i-use-regular-headphones-on-transatlantic-british-airways-747-flights):

I'd like to use BA headphones (with a dual 3.5mm connector) with my own laptop during the flight, in stereo.

Is there a good solution for this?

Comment: Just curious, but why?  Are the airline-provided headphones nice in some way?  My experience on other airlines is that the provided headphones are of the cheapest possible kind, and you could almost certainly get better headphones (or earbuds) for less than the cost of the adapter.

Comment: I find BA's headphones in business and first to be just fine, and don't want to carry my own just to use on the plane. (I travel with nothing but one fairly small carry-on bag.)

Comment: The answer on the other question suggests that the headphones in business and first use a single stereo 3.5mm plug, plus a separate 2.5mm plug for noise cancellation.  You may be able to just plug the 3.5 mm plug directly into your laptop, if you can orient it so that the 2.5mm plug is not in the way.  Or use a simple 3.5mm single stereo extension cable.

Comment: BA still using dual plugs in Business and First classes ?

Comment: @Max: I generally don't pay a lot of attention to these things, but my most recent DEN-LHR flight in Club World certainly did use dual plugs. (I only noticed because own headphones had failed; this made me wonder whether I can ditch mine and just use BA's next time.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: If that's the case, problem solved. Thanks. I'll try tomorrow. (I didn't look at the BA connectors closely enough to see whether they were TS or TRS; I just assumed they carried one mono channel each.)

Comment: Though I guess it's also possible that the 2.5mm plug carries *power* for the headphones.  If so then maybe you'd also need a 2.5mm extension cable and plug it into the seat jack.  Maybe someone with direct experience can answer.  Anyhow, I'd suggest you edit your question to clarify that you are talking about J/F class.

Comment: I cannot answer specifically for BA, but yes, usually the 2,5 mm jack transports the power for the noise cancelling functionality.

Comment: @Max may well depend on the aircraft, when the specific one was in to have its cabin upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

This forum [post](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/18319546-post15.html) says

> I have used the BA headphones in my iPod, you just have to twist the jack so that only the larger jack plug goes into the iPod.

Answer (score -1):

You can get an adapter for it. They are very small and work well.

Some airlines will provide you with noise-cancelling headphones with a normal plug though.

Comment: Nope, that's the two 2.5" mono plugs to 3.5" stereo plug, BA is different. Made you an album: https://imgur.com/a/i0G5vDC The two red rings on each plug on the photo of the headphone are very well visible and the size difference is also visible if you zoom in a bit, the adapter photo shows one ring per plug and the plugs are the same size.

Comment: @chx maybe you could add a picture of the plug in your question?

Comment: Hrm? I did, it's right there.

Comment: @chx ah, you didn't ask the question.